# ReferenceError: enzyme_1 is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, ts-jest

The test suite was running just fine until it didn't. The weird thing is happening only in my machine, CI works all right.

Our project uses Typecript, React, Jest and Enzyme and this is what I get when I run `yarn jest`:

```
Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: enzyme_1 is not defined

  6 | // (global as any).jQuery = $
  7 |
> 8 | Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
    | ^
  9 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (spec/javascripts/setupTests.ts:8:1)
```

I tried cleaning yarn cache, cloning the repo again, reinstalling node. I am absolutely clueless. Any ideas?

Relevant config files:

- https://github.com/3scale/porta/blob/master/jest.config.js
- https://github.com/3scale/porta/blob/master/tsconfig.json
- https://github.com/3scale/porta/blob/master/spec/javascripts/setupTests.ts

EDIT:

This error is happening with node `10.19.0`. After installing `12.22.2` the error shows a new message:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'enzyme_1' before initialization
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is some inconsistency between the `tsconfig` and `jest.config` regarding js modules.

In the tsconfig the module resolution is set to `Node` and module to `ES6`, whereas the jest config file uses the preset `ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel` which will transform `.ts` files to `CommonJS`.

In fact, if `setupTests.js` is used instead of `setupTests.ts`, the tests run without errors.

**Solution A (node oriented):**
Set module to `CommonJS` in tsconfig.

```
-  "module": "ES6",
+  "module": "CommonJS",
```

**Solution B (web oriented):**
Use an appropriate preset, in this case `ts-jest/presets/default-esm` to transform `.ts` files into ES modules.

```
- preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel',
+ preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
```

Additionally, `moduleResolution` should be `NodeNext` for ESM, not `Node`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution